# Exit a parallel block SPD 2013 but 2010 workflow

Tags: 2013, 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I've looked around a lot but haven't found a solution yet, so here goes:

I am trying to create a parallel block in a workflow in SPD 2013 (making use of 2010 workflows) but instead of it being an AND block, I want this to be an OR block. If either one of the task is complete, exit the parallel block.

I've used the logic from this website: https://threewill.com/waiting-change-workflow/

[image]

The pause would be one day in the actual flow.

But here is the problem/question. I want to set the advanced properties: completionCondition to doneWaiting  equals yes, but I can't:

[image]

I do not have the ability to select a variable in the dropdown.

Can someone tell me how this works with 2010 workflows in SDP 2013? Or is there an other (better) way to achieve this?

Thank you!

Note: In general what I want to achieve is this:

If after one day the task is not completed, user 1 receives a reminder. After another day user 2 receives a reminder if the task hasn't been completed in the meantime. But, if the task is completed in the meantime, the reminders shouldn't be sent out. An other workflow sets the reminder status to the next value once a task is completed.

Comment: Have you found out why the YES and NO Options are not selectable? I have the same problem and I need to exit the parallel block if one of my actions are finished whereby I start two parallel Task Processes.

Answer (score 1):

I like your creativity but I think there may be a better way.

I suggest taking advantage of the existing SP2010 WF task process expiration capabilities.

1. When the Task Process is started from the parent workflow, right-click and set your expiration conditions [image: designer wf screenshot]
2. You can also calculate and set a Due Date (in your case, one day after task initiation) in the When a Task is Pending section of the Task Process.
3. Let the When a Task Expires section do the heavy lifting. Anything in this section will run every time an individual task expires. Set a workflow variable (call it something like 'expirationCount') to 0 earlier in the workflow. As soon as When a Task Expires starts, check if expirationCount == 0. If so, this is the first late notice. If it's greater than one, send an email with different recipients.

At the end of the Task Expires section, increment your count variable.

[image]